# class Action is deprecated

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, magento2.4.2

I am following a tutorial about Magento version 2.4.2, and I am getting a problem while using Action as It shows deprecation,
and also even after cleaning cache, the error shown is *Required parameter 'theme_dir' was not passed*

This is my code if anyone has an idea

```
<?php
namespace SimplifiedMagento\RequestFlow\Controller\Page;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;

class CustomNoRoute extends Action
{

    public function execute()
    {
        echo "this is our custom 404";
    }
}
```

The code after update

```
namespace SimplifiedMagento\RequestFlow\Controller\Page;

use Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;

class CustomNoRoute implements ActionInterface
{

    public function execute()
    {
        echo "this is our custom 404";
    }
}
```

I got this new error after resolving a problem related to the theme

```
Call to a member function get() on null in C:\xampp-clean\htdocs\magento242\vendor\magento\framework\App\Action\Action.php:109 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp-clean\htdocs\magento242\vendor\magento\framework\App\FrontController.php(186): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http)) #1 C:\xampp-clean\htdocs\magento242\vendor\magento\framework\App\FrontController.php
```

Well after changing my code to this

```
<?php
namespace SimplifiedMagento\RequestFlow\Controller\Page;

 use Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface;
 use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;

class CustomNoRoute implements ActionInterface


 {

    public function execute()
    {
        echo "this is our custom 404";
     }
   }
```

I am getting this output :

```
this is our custom 4041 exception(s):
Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Invalid return type

Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Invalid return type
<pre>#1 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor\magento\framework\App\Bootstrap.php:263]
#2 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() called at [pub\index.php:29]
</pre>
```

So at least it is echoing the result ;

Thanks in advance

Comment: What you want to do with controller? I mean what action perform by controller?

Comment: Showing 404 error

Answer (score 1):

You should implement `Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface` instead of extending `Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action`.

Depending on the purpose of your Action, you can also use a more specific interface like `Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpGetActionInterface` to limit the Action to specific requests types.

Example:

```
...
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpGetActionInterface;

class Index implements HttpGetActionInterface
{
...
```

For more information about Action classes, take a look in the [Magento DevDocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/routing.html#action-class).

Also, you cannot just use `echo` to output something on the page from an Action. See [Result object in the DevDocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/routing.html#result-object) for possible return values. You might want to return a *page* result object that will render a specific page defined using layout XML and phtml templates. You could also use *raw* for testing purposes like outputting a simple string.

Comment: Thanks but I am still having , the same problem , check my code updated

Comment: I got this new errror

Comment: Call to a member function get() on null in C:\xampp-clean\htdocs\magento242\vendor\magento\framework\App\Action\Action.php:109 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp-clean\htdocs\magento242\vendor\magento\framework\App\FrontController.php(186): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http)) #1 C:\xampp-clean\htdocs\magento242\vendor\magento\framework\App\FrontController.php

Answer (score 0):

This error is not cause of controller I guess, Please check that all the rows in the table has value **0** for **type** field (especially activated theme).

***magento_database -> theme.***

[image]

Comment: This is  the new error : Error: Call to a member function get() on null in C:\xampp-clean\htdocs\magento242\vendor\magento\frame

Answer (score 0):

Try code like this one :

```
namespace SimplifiedMagento\RequestFlow\Controller\Page;


class CustomNoRoute extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

     public function __construct(
       \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
       \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\ForwardFactory $resultForwardFactory
     ) {
        $this->resultForwardFactory = $resultForwardFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
     }

    public function execute()
    {
        echo "this is our custom 404";
    }
}
```

Comment: can you help me on this case: https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/345241/86511
thanks in advance !!