# magento 2.3 display first two product images on details page

Tags: magento2.3, theme, product-page, luma-theme

i am using magento 2.3 version and i am using custom theme so i want to product page in main image showing first two images so when main image sliding and another coming it and rest first same like it

[image]

and i have this file try to modification but i can't achieve it

```
magento2/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/gallery.phtml
```

i know everything coming on this file but i can't set it

can you help me on this case?

Thanks!!

Comment: On that file you need to implement whole slider code, then and then it will fullfill your requirement.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya yes right can you suggest me code for that thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make these changes in your theme directory.
Create a directory Magento_Catalog inside your theme eq.

app/design/frontend/parenttheme/yourtheme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view
create a file gallery.phtml

Inside the above path. Copy the content from

vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/gallery.phtml

Make necessary changes.

run php bin/magento c:f

and check.

If the file already exists in the theme directory then make changes you need and clear the cache.

Comment: yes right can you suggest me code for that thanks!!